# Decide whether a graph is planar or not

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A simple connected graph has 20 vertices and 22 edges.Decide whether given graph is planar or not(if answer is yes prove it otherwise give counter example)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** By Kuratowski-Wagner it suffices to check, whether the graph contains a subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$. Hence you may as well reduce to consider such subdivisions. Can you construct a subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ on $n$ vertices by using at most $n+2$ edges?

Comment: I think no so by just saying we cannot construct such sibdivision is enough?

Comment: but how can we be sure that we can not construct such sub divison?

Comment: A graph is planar if it does **not** contain such a subdivision. So if you can show that such a subdivision cannot exist, any graph on $n$ vertices with less than $n+2$ edges is planar

Comment: how can we show that?

Comment: It is graph theory: induction and counting things ;)

Comment: But I dont understand in this way)

Comment: How many edges does $K_5$ have? How many does $K_{3,3}$ have? If you subdivide an edge (put a vertex on it) what happens to the number of vertices/edges?

Comment: K5 have 15edges and K33 have 9edges

Comment: can u tell me how can i find out?

Comment: I think $K_5$ has 10 edges. Anyway 5+2 < 10, 6+2 < 9, so ...?

Comment: so  it cannot have such subgraph because the edges must be more than n+2?

Comment: Exactly. You have to show by induction on the number of vertices that any subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ with $n$ vertices has more than $n+2$ edges. We just did the induction base.